# Probability - Coin toss - Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have been unable to crack this question:

A fair coin is tossed $n$ times. What is the probability of heads on the first toss given that $r$ heads were obtained in the $n$ tosses?

From: http://personal.vu.nl/h.c.tijms/ExamQuestionsUP.pdf

The solution uses conditional probability (which I am unfamiliar with, however, did search to understand). If anyone could explain that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

It can be rephrased like this:

If there are $n$ balls in an urn and exactly $r$ of them are red, then - if you pick out one  ball - what is the probability that the ball is red?

Comment: Thanks, why can it be rephrased like that? That makes much more sense (obviously) than the given question... what is different between the two question (eg. how did you transform it into that question?)

Comment: There are $r$ heads/red balls among the $n$ tosses/balls, and one outcome is selected. It just does not matter whether that is first or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

Let $A$ be the event that the first toss is heads. Let $B$ be the event that $r$ heads are obtained in the first $n$ tosses. The number of ways to get $r$ heads when flipping a coin $n$ times is $\binom{n}{r}$. The number of ways to get $r$ heads and also have the first toss be heads is $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$. (Reason: Of the remaining $n - 1$ tosses, we need to select $r - 1$ of them to be heads.) Thus,
\begin{align}
P(A \mid B ) &= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \\
&= \frac{\binom{n-1}{r-1}}{\binom{n}{r}} \\
&= \frac{r}{n}.
\end{align}